# Identify C++ exception thrown in terminate

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to identify what type of exception was thrown in the `terminate` handler I set with `set_terminate`?

I would like for programs in my suite to pop up a message box if one of *my* exceptions is thrown, but not if the exception came from elsewhere.

Edit:  code tried based on Brian's answer below.  It doesn't do any of the cout's after the throw;

```
// set_terminate example
#include <iostream>       // std::cerr
#include <exception>      // std::set_terminate
#include <cstdlib>        // std::abort

using namespace std;

class FooException {};
class BarException {};

void my_terminate() {
    try {
        cout << "This line gets printed... those below do not.\n";
        throw; // rethrows
    } 
    catch (FooException) {
        cout << "FooException.\n";
        // pop up message box
    } 
    catch (BarException) {
        cout << "BarException.\n";
        // pop up message box
    } 
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Unclassified exception.\n";
        // not one of my exceptions
        abort();
    }
    cout << "Doesn't print this either.\n";
}

int main (void) 
{
  std::set_terminate (my_terminate);
  throw FooException ();
  return 0;
}
```

This may be a Visual Studio problem.  (It won't call dtors either on its way out.) I'm going to ask another question about getting Visual to go to the right places, and then try addressing this question again.

Answer (score 3):

An exception is still considered "active" inside the terminate handler (see C++11 §15.3/7 and §15.3/8). Therefore it can be rethrown or accessed with `current_exception`.

```
void my_terminate() {
    try {
        throw; // rethrows
    } catch (FooException) {
        // pop up message box
    } catch (BarException) {
        // pop up message box
    } catch (...) {
        // not one of my exceptions
        abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Love the idea!  When I do it, though (see code appended to original post), it doesn't do any of the catches.  Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @WillBriggs Please post a complete self-contained example.

Comment: @WillBriggs: Try using `endl` instead of `\n`. This forces `cout` to flush.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.  I just put that in.  It's still not reaching the catch blocks, it seems.

Comment: I use MSVS2008 and it does not catch for me in my_terminate()

What IDEs do you use guys ? What OS ?
I guess M$ is kinda different here, as quite often :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own exception-base-class, catch all exceptions in main and re-throw all exceptions derived from your base-class. this way, only your exceptions will terminate the Programm with `terminate`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to derive all exception classes from std::exception

Then you can do

```
 try
 {
 }
 catch . . .
 catch . . .
 catch . . .
 catch (std::exception &ee)
 {
    cerr << ee.what () << end ;
 }
```

and be sure to catch everything.

Comment: In the terminate handler?  Can't put it in main.  Maybe some other handler?